# XOR and typecasting

Tags: java, casting, xor

I'm writing an encryption/decryption program using bitwise xor operation. Given a character array and an array with int as keys, I xor the first character of the array with the first key. For the other characters I xor them with the next int in the key array and then xor again with the previous encrypted character. `enc[i] = enc[i - 1] ^ k[i] ^ c[i]` where c is the character to be encrypted, k the key, and enc the encrypted character. I do get the correct result if I don't xor with the previous encrypted character.

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        char[] charArray1 = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
        int[] keys1 = genereateKeys(charArray1.length);
        
        int[] encrypted1 = encrypt(charArray1, keys1);
        printCharArray(decrypt(encrypted1, keys1));

        char[] charArray2 = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'};
        int[] keys2 = genereateKeys(charArray2.length);
        
        int[] encrypted2 = encrypt(charArray2, keys2);
        printCharArray(decrypt(encrypted2, keys2));
    }

    public static void printCharArray(char[] letter){
        for(int i = 0; i < letter.length; ++i)
            System.out.print(letter[i]);
        
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static int[] encrypt(char[] letters, int[] keys){
        int[] msg = new int[letters.length];
        msg[0] = ((int)letters[0]) ^ keys[0];
        for(int i = 1; i < letters.length; ++i){
            msg[i] = ((int)letters[i]) ^ keys[i] ^ msg[i - 1];
        }
        return msg;
    }

    public static char[] decrypt(int[] letters, int[] keys){
        char[] msg = new char[letters.length];
        msg[0] = (char)(letters[0] ^ keys[0]);
        for(int i = 1; i < letters.length; ++i){
            msg[i] = (char)(letters[i] ^ keys[i]) ^ (int)msg[i - 1]);
        }
        return msg;
    }

}
```

So what exactly am I doing wrong here? As I said when I encrypt/decrypt without the before element the result is as expected. The problem is when i xor with the before element.

Comment: Please call this operation "obfuscation", not "encryption" - because that's what it is (and what it is not). Also, what's `en` and `de`?

Comment: @OlafKock i had forgotten to remove those. I just have different classes for encryption and decryption, that's why they were there.

Comment: why are keys not `char[]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must XOR with the same previous element.

Currently when encrypting you use

```
msg[i] = letters[i] ^ keys[i] ^ msg[i - 1];
```

where `msg[i - 1]` is the encrypted previous character.

When decrypting you use

```
msg[i] = (char)(letters[i] ^ keys[i] ^ msg[i - 1]);
```

where `msg[i - 1]` is the decrypted previous character.

You can either use

```
msg[i] = (char)(letters[i] ^ keys[i] ^ letter[i - 1]);
```

when decrypting, or use

```
msg[i] = letters[i] ^ keys[i] ^ letters[i - 1];
```

when encrypting.

---

Note: from the comments, some say that is is mere obfuscation.

But: this is IMHO an application of the [One-Time Pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) algorithm if you create a unique key in `genereateKeys(charArray1.length)` - and **a properly done** One-Time Pad is an encryption technique that cannot be cracked.

The emphasis is on "properly done" because this technique of course requires that both sender (encryptor) and receiver (decryptor) must know the One-Time Pad and the difficulty is in securely transfering that One-Time Pad from the sender to the receiver of the message.